# If sum of column not including the last row = to the value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a sub that will delete the total row in a financial statement if the sum of the values in the entire column (not including the last row, as that is the total) is **equal** to the cell in the last row we did not include (total amount)

```
Dim number As Double
Dim RowDelete As Long


RowDelete = Cells(Rows.Count, 36).End(xlUp).Row

number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(RowDelete - 1, 1)))

If number = RowDelete Then

Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Delete


End If
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the last row?

Comment: In the variable - the sum of all values in column A, except for the last row that has a value in it.  For example let's say column A has values 2,2,2,6 - the 6 being the total of the above numbers.  I would like to declare ````numbers```` as the total of 2,2,2 but not 6.  This is common in accounting as we are always including a total row.   The number of rows are always changing, so I cannot use a fixed range.

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.Subtotal` with function ID 9 (SUM)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your total number is on the last row, you could just skip the last row:

Do it by: `lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` - check which row is the last one

`Cells(1, 1)` -> Cells(Row nr, Column nr)

**Code:**

```
Sub ifSum()

Dim number As Double
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow - 1, 1)))

If number = Range("C1") Then

Range("D4").FormulaR1C1 = "Hello!"

Else

Range("D4").FormulaR1C1 = "Goodbye!"

End If

End Sub
```

---

This "test code" seem to work for me:

```
Sub ifSum()

Dim number As Double
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

number = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow - 1, 1)))

If number = lRow Then

Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Given my sheet looks like this, it will remove in this case the row 15 (with the test code above):

[image]

Comment: Lovely to hear, thanks. Feel free to mark the answer as solved by tick in the grey arrow/tick mark below the voting buttons. It helps other people to see that your question is solved :)!

Comment: Edit: When plugged into my original sub it is returning a syntax error -    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j8Vb.png

Comment: Does it work better if you use: `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Delete`. This line of code seem to cause the error, at least for me. The syntax error is not specific. The reason for that could be that some line in your code is incomplete/missing part/brackets not closed etc..

Comment: Thanks.  The row isn`t giving me that error anymore, however there is a new one stating an object-defined error.  See updated code above.